# Trim result with RegEx

Tags: php, arrays, regex, trim

Using the following in PHP:

```
var_dump($obj->denormalized->{'https://api.site.com/user/user-76643221'}->data->avatar_image)
```

Results:

```
string(56) "https://api.site.com/image_link/user-76643221_b691647a"
```

I only need the link, without those extra parts. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`var_dump` shows the types and sizes of variables; it's meant for debugging. If you only need the link, then instead of using `var_dump` use `print` or `echo`

```
echo $obj->denormalized->{'https://api.site.com/user/user-76643221'}->data->avatar_image;
```

Results:

```
https://api.site.com/image_link/user-76643221_b691647a
```